# Set up an iPhone-based web interface in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I saw years ago apps where you could activate a web interface over the iPhone. For example to control the app over the web browser.

I searched a lot for that but I could't find a solution that works.

I found [here](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/09/creating-an-iphone-based-web-s.html) a tutorial but it doesn't work. There are a lot of errors while compiling, a lot of functions that don't exist.

Could you give me an example how to manage that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a simple HTTP server handling at least HTTP 1.1 `GET` commands.

Open a server socket on your iPhone, and just answer `GET` request properly.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need to do. But how? I never worked with CFNetworks or something like that... Do you have a code example?

Comment: Use POSIX API for sockets. There are plenty of examples on the internet. Just GOOGLE: "berkeley socket API".

Comment: That was the tip I needed! Thank you.